# OutlineEffect error when fog is enabled, invalid shaders ERROR: 0:204: 'fogDepth' : redefinition

Tags: three.js, vertex-shader

I'm trying to build a three.js scene using the OutlineEffect.js from the examples (https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/dev/examples/js/effects/OutlineEffect.js).  This works great.

However, when I add fog to the scene, I then get this error, and the outline doesn't show up:

```
THREE.WebGLProgram: shader error:  1282 gl.VALIDATE_STATUS false gl.getProgramInfoLog invalid shaders ERROR: 0:204: 'fogDepth' : redefinition
```

The relevant parts of the code (I hope) are:

```
var outline = new THREE.OutlineEffect(window.renderer, {
  defaultThickness : window.sceneSettings.lineThickness
});

if (window.sceneSettings.useFog) {
  var newFog = new THREE.Fog(0xffffff, window.sceneSettings.fogNear, window.sceneSettings.fogFar)
  scene.fog = newFog
}

function render(e) {
  outline.render(scene, window.camera)
}
```

I apologize if this question is naive; I'm not really a js or threejs person, I'm a data scientist trying to feel my way around this.

Thank you in advance for any advice!

EDIT:

More from the logs:

The first error is `three.module.js:16963 THREE.WebGLShader: Shader couldn't compile.` with the following source dump:

```
THREE.WebGLShader: gl.getShaderInfoLog() vertex ERROR: 0:178: 'fogDepth' : redefinition
 1: precision highp float;
2: precision highp int;
3: #define SHADER_NAME ShaderMaterial
4: #define VERTEX_TEXTURES
5: #define GAMMA_FACTOR 2
6: #define MAX_BONES 0
7: #define USE_FOG
8: #define BONE_TEXTURE
9: #define FLIP_SIDED
10: uniform mat4 modelMatrix;
11: uniform mat4 modelViewMatrix;
12: uniform mat4 projectionMatrix;
13: uniform mat4 viewMatrix;
14: uniform mat3 normalMatrix;
15: uniform vec3 cameraPosition;
16: attribute vec3 position;
17: attribute vec3 normal;
18: attribute vec2 uv;
19: #ifdef USE_COLOR
20:     attribute vec3 color;
21: #endif
22: #ifdef USE_MORPHTARGETS
23:     attribute vec3 morphTarget0;
24:     attribute vec3 morphTarget1;
25:     attribute vec3 morphTarget2;
26:     attribute vec3 morphTarget3;
27:     #ifdef USE_MORPHNORMALS
28:         attribute vec3 morphNormal0;
29:         attribute vec3 morphNormal1;
30:         attribute vec3 morphNormal2;
31:         attribute vec3 morphNormal3;
32:     #else
33:         attribute vec3 morphTarget4;
34:         attribute vec3 morphTarget5;
35:         attribute vec3 morphTarget6;
36:         attribute vec3 morphTarget7;
37:     #endif
38: #endif
39: #ifdef USE_SKINNING
40:     attribute vec4 skinIndex;
41:     attribute vec4 skinWeight;
42: #endif
43: 
44: #define PI 3.14159265359
45: #define PI2 6.28318530718
46: #define PI_HALF 1.5707963267949
47: #define RECIPROCAL_PI 0.31830988618
48: #define RECIPROCAL_PI2 0.15915494
49: #define LOG2 1.442695
50: #define EPSILON 1e-6
51: #define saturate(a) clamp( a, 0.0, 1.0 )
52: #define whiteCompliment(a) ( 1.0 - saturate( a ) )
53: float pow2( const in float x ) { return x*x; }
54: float pow3( const in float x ) { return x*x*x; }
55: float pow4( const in float x ) { float x2 = x*x; return x2*x2; }
56: float average( const in vec3 color ) { return dot( color, vec3( 0.3333 ) ); }
57: highp float rand( const in vec2 uv ) {
58:     const highp float a = 12.9898, b = 78.233, c = 43758.5453;
59:     highp float dt = dot( uv.xy, vec2( a,b ) ), sn = mod( dt, PI );
60:     return fract(sin(sn) * c);
61: }
62: struct IncidentLight {
63:     vec3 color;
64:     vec3 direction;
65:     bool visible;
66: };
67: struct ReflectedLight {
68:     vec3 directDiffuse;
69:     vec3 directSpecular;
70:     vec3 indirectDiffuse;
71:     vec3 indirectSpecular;
72: };
73: struct GeometricContext {
74:     vec3 position;
75:     vec3 normal;
76:     vec3 viewDir;
77: };
78: vec3 transformDirection( in vec3 dir, in mat4 matrix ) {
79:     return normalize( ( matrix * vec4( dir, 0.0 ) ).xyz );
80: }
81: vec3 inverseTransformDirection( in vec3 dir, in mat4 matrix ) {
82:     return normalize( ( vec4( dir, 0.0 ) * matrix ).xyz );
83: }
84: vec3 projectOnPlane(in vec3 point, in vec3 pointOnPlane, in vec3 planeNormal ) {
85:     float distance = dot( planeNormal, point - pointOnPlane );
86:     return - distance * planeNormal + point;
87: }
88: float sideOfPlane( in vec3 point, in vec3 pointOnPlane, in vec3 planeNormal ) {
89:     return sign( dot( point - pointOnPlane, planeNormal ) );
90: }
91: vec3 linePlaneIntersect( in vec3 pointOnLine, in vec3 lineDirection, in vec3 pointOnPlane, in vec3 planeNormal ) {
92:     return lineDirection * ( dot( planeNormal, pointOnPlane - pointOnLine ) / dot( planeNormal, lineDirection ) ) + pointOnLine;
93: }
94: mat3 transposeMat3( const in mat3 m ) {
95:     mat3 tmp;
96:     tmp[ 0 ] = vec3( m[ 0 ].x, m[ 1 ].x, m[ 2 ].x );
97:     tmp[ 1 ] = vec3( m[ 0 ].y, m[ 1 ].y, m[ 2 ].y );
98:     tmp[ 2 ] = vec3( m[ 0 ].z, m[ 1 ].z, m[ 2 ].z );
99:     return tmp;
100: }
101: float linearToRelativeLuminance( const in vec3 color ) {
102:    vec3 weights = vec3( 0.2126, 0.7152, 0.0722 );
103:    return dot( weights, color.rgb );
104: }
105: 
106: #if defined( USE_MAP ) || defined( USE_BUMPMAP ) || defined( USE_NORMALMAP ) || defined( USE_SPECULARMAP ) || defined( USE_ALPHAMAP ) || defined( USE_EMISSIVEMAP ) || defined( USE_ROUGHNESSMAP ) || defined( USE_METALNESSMAP )
107:    varying vec2 vUv;
108:    uniform mat3 uvTransform;
109: #endif
110: 
111: #if defined( USE_LIGHTMAP ) || defined( USE_AOMAP )
112:    attribute vec2 uv2;
113:    varying vec2 vUv2;
114: #endif
115: #ifdef USE_ENVMAP
116:    #if defined( USE_BUMPMAP ) || defined( USE_NORMALMAP ) || defined( PHONG )
117:        varying vec3 vWorldPosition;
118:    #else
119:        varying vec3 vReflect;
120:        uniform float refractionRatio;
121:    #endif
122: #endif
123: 
124: #ifdef USE_COLOR
125:    varying vec3 vColor;
126: #endif
127: #ifdef USE_FOG
128:   varying float fogDepth;
129: #endif
130: 
131: #ifdef USE_MORPHTARGETS
132:    #ifndef USE_MORPHNORMALS
133:    uniform float morphTargetInfluences[ 8 ];
134:    #else
135:    uniform float morphTargetInfluences[ 4 ];
136:    #endif
137: #endif
138: #ifdef USE_SKINNING
139:    uniform mat4 bindMatrix;
140:    uniform mat4 bindMatrixInverse;
141:    #ifdef BONE_TEXTURE
142:        uniform sampler2D boneTexture;
143:        uniform int boneTextureSize;
144:        mat4 getBoneMatrix( const in float i ) {
145:            float j = i * 4.0;
146:            float x = mod( j, float( boneTextureSize ) );
147:            float y = floor( j / float( boneTextureSize ) );
148:            float dx = 1.0 / float( boneTextureSize );
149:            float dy = 1.0 / float( boneTextureSize );
150:            y = dy * ( y + 0.5 );
151:            vec4 v1 = texture2D( boneTexture, vec2( dx * ( x + 0.5 ), y ) );
152:            vec4 v2 = texture2D( boneTexture, vec2( dx * ( x + 1.5 ), y ) );
153:            vec4 v3 = texture2D( boneTexture, vec2( dx * ( x + 2.5 ), y ) );
154:            vec4 v4 = texture2D( boneTexture, vec2( dx * ( x + 3.5 ), y ) );
155:            mat4 bone = mat4( v1, v2, v3, v4 );
156:            return bone;
157:        }
158:    #else
159:        uniform mat4 boneMatrices[ MAX_BONES ];
160:        mat4 getBoneMatrix( const in float i ) {
161:            mat4 bone = boneMatrices[ int(i) ];
162:            return bone;
163:        }
164:    #endif
165: #endif
166: 
167: #ifdef USE_LOGDEPTHBUF
168:    #ifdef USE_LOGDEPTHBUF_EXT
169:        varying float vFragDepth;
170:    #endif
171:    uniform float logDepthBufFC;
172: #endif
173: #if 0 > 0 && ! defined( PHYSICAL ) && ! defined( PHONG )
174:    varying vec3 vViewPosition;
175: #endif
176: 
177: #ifdef USE_FOG
178:   varying float fogDepth;
179: #endif
180: 
181: uniform float outlineThickness;
182: vec4 calculateOutline( vec4 pos, vec3 objectNormal, vec4 skinned ) {
183:    float thickness = outlineThickness;
184:    const float ratio = 1.0;
185:    vec4 pos2 = projectionMatrix * modelViewMatrix * vec4( skinned.xyz + objectNormal, 1.0 );
186:    vec4 norm = normalize( pos - pos2 );
187:    return pos + norm * thickness * pos.w * ratio;
188: }
189: void main() {
190: #if defined( USE_MAP ) || defined( USE_BUMPMAP ) || defined( USE_NORMALMAP ) || defined( USE_SPECULARMAP ) || defined( USE_ALPHAMAP ) || defined( USE_EMISSIVEMAP ) || defined( USE_ROUGHNESSMAP ) || defined( USE_METALNESSMAP )
191:    vUv = ( uvTransform * vec3( uv, 1 ) ).xy;
192: #endif
193: #if defined( USE_LIGHTMAP ) || defined( USE_AOMAP )
194:    vUv2 = uv2;
195: #endif
196: #ifdef USE_COLOR
197:    vColor.xyz = color.xyz;
198: #endif
199: #ifdef USE_SKINNING
200:    mat4 boneMatX = getBoneMatrix( skinIndex.x );
201:    mat4 boneMatY = getBoneMatrix( skinIndex.y );
202:    mat4 boneMatZ = getBoneMatrix( skinIndex.z );
203:    mat4 boneMatW = getBoneMatrix( skinIndex.w );
204: #endif
205:    #ifdef USE_ENVMAP
206: 
207: vec3 objectNormal = vec3( normal );
208: 
209: #ifdef USE_MORPHNORMALS
210:    objectNormal += ( morphNormal0 - normal ) * morphTargetInfluences[ 0 ];
211:    objectNormal += ( morphNormal1 - normal ) * morphTargetInfluences[ 1 ];
212:    objectNormal += ( morphNormal2 - normal ) * morphTargetInfluences[ 2 ];
213:    objectNormal += ( morphNormal3 - normal ) * morphTargetInfluences[ 3 ];
214: #endif
215: 
216: #ifdef USE_SKINNING
217:    mat4 skinMatrix = mat4( 0.0 );
218:    skinMatrix += skinWeight.x * boneMatX;
219:    skinMatrix += skinWeight.y * boneMatY;
220:    skinMatrix += skinWeight.z * boneMatZ;
221:    skinMatrix += skinWeight.w * boneMatW;
222:    skinMatrix  = bindMatrixInverse * skinMatrix * bindMatrix;
223:    objectNormal = vec4( skinMatrix * vec4( objectNormal, 0.0 ) ).xyz;
224: #endif
225: 
226: vec3 transformedNormal = normalMatrix * objectNormal;
227: #ifdef FLIP_SIDED
228:    transformedNormal = - transformedNormal;
229: #endif
230: 
231:    #endif
232: 
233: vec3 transformed = vec3( position );
234: 
235: #ifdef USE_MORPHTARGETS
236:    transformed += ( morphTarget0 - position ) * morphTargetInfluences[ 0 ];
237:    transformed += ( morphTarget1 - position ) * morphTargetInfluences[ 1 ];
238:    transformed += ( morphTarget2 - position ) * morphTargetInfluences[ 2 ];
239:    transformed += ( morphTarget3 - position ) * morphTargetInfluences[ 3 ];
240:    #ifndef USE_MORPHNORMALS
241:    transformed += ( morphTarget4 - position ) * morphTargetInfluences[ 4 ];
242:    transformed += ( morphTarget5 - position ) * morphTargetInfluences[ 5 ];
243:    transformed += ( morphTarget6 - position ) * morphTargetInfluences[ 6 ];
244:    transformed += ( morphTarget7 - position ) * morphTargetInfluences[ 7 ];
245:    #endif
246: #endif
247: 
248: #ifdef USE_SKINNING
249:    vec4 skinVertex = bindMatrix * vec4( transformed, 1.0 );
250:    vec4 skinned = vec4( 0.0 );
251:    skinned += boneMatX * skinVertex * skinWeight.x;
252:    skinned += boneMatY * skinVertex * skinWeight.y;
253:    skinned += boneMatZ * skinVertex * skinWeight.z;
254:    skinned += boneMatW * skinVertex * skinWeight.w;
255:    transformed = ( bindMatrixInverse * skinned ).xyz;
256: #endif
257: 
258: vec4 mvPosition = modelViewMatrix * vec4( transformed, 1.0 );
259: gl_Position = projectionMatrix * mvPosition;
260: 
261: #ifdef USE_LOGDEPTHBUF
262:    #ifdef USE_LOGDEPTHBUF_EXT
263:        vFragDepth = 1.0 + gl_Position.w;
264:    #else
265:        gl_Position.z = log2( max( EPSILON, gl_Position.w + 1.0 ) ) * logDepthBufFC - 1.0;
266:        gl_Position.z *= gl_Position.w;
267:    #endif
268: #endif
269: 
270: #if defined( USE_ENVMAP ) || defined( DISTANCE ) || defined ( USE_SHADOWMAP )
271:    vec4 worldPosition = modelMatrix * vec4( transformed, 1.0 );
272: #endif
273: 
274: #if 0 > 0 && ! defined( PHYSICAL ) && ! defined( PHONG )
275:    vViewPosition = - mvPosition.xyz;
276: #endif
277: 
278: #ifdef USE_ENVMAP
279:    #if defined( USE_BUMPMAP ) || defined( USE_NORMALMAP ) || defined( PHONG )
280:        vWorldPosition = worldPosition.xyz;
281:    #else
282:        vec3 cameraToVertex = normalize( worldPosition.xyz - cameraPosition );
283:        vec3 worldNormal = inverseTransformDirection( transformedNormal, viewMatrix );
284:        #ifdef ENVMAP_MODE_REFLECTION
285:            vReflect = reflect( cameraToVertex, worldNormal );
286:        #else
287:            vReflect = refract( cameraToVertex, worldNormal, refractionRatio );
288:        #endif
289:    #endif
290: #endif
291: 
292: 
293: #ifdef USE_FOG
294: fogDepth = -mvPosition.z;
295: #endif
296: #if ! defined( LAMBERT ) && ! defined( PHONG ) && ! defined( TOON ) && ! defined( PHYSICAL )
297:    #ifndef USE_ENVMAP
298:        vec3 objectNormal = normalize( normal );
299:    #endif
300: #endif
301: #ifdef FLIP_SIDED
302:    objectNormal = -objectNormal;
303: #endif
304: #ifdef DECLARE_TRANSFORMED
305:    vec3 transformed = vec3( position );
306: #endif
307: gl_Position = calculateOutline( gl_Position, objectNormal, vec4( transformed, 1.0 ) );
308: 
309: #ifdef USE_FOG
310: fogDepth = -mvPosition.z;
311: #endif
312: }
```

That code isn't in the OutlineEffect source.  But the way OutlineEffect works, it includes this code where it redefines the vertex shader code using a regex:

```
var vertexShader = originalVertexShader
            // put vertexShaderChunk right before "void main() {...}"
            .replace( /void\s+main\s*\(\s*\)/, vertexShaderChunk + '\nvoid main()' )
            // put vertexShaderChunk2 the end of "void main() {...}"
            // Note: here assums originalVertexShader ends with "}" of "void main() {...}"
            .replace( /\}\s*$/, vertexShaderChunk2 + '\n}' )
            // remove any light related lines
            // Note: here is very sensitive to originalVertexShader
            // TODO: consider safer way
            .replace( /#include\s+<[\w_]*light[\w_]*>/g, '' );
```

And here is the source dump from the error that refers to line 204 (note that I'm cutting these lengthy source dumps after the relevant line)

```
gl.getShaderInfoLog() vertex ERROR: 0:204: 'fogDepth' : redefinition
 1: precision highp float;
2: precision highp int;
3: #define SHADER_NAME ShaderMaterial
4: #define VERTEX_TEXTURES
5: #define GAMMA_FACTOR 2
6: #define MAX_BONES 0
7: #define USE_FOG
8: #define BONE_TEXTURE
9: #define FLIP_SIDED
10: uniform mat4 modelMatrix;
11: uniform mat4 modelViewMatrix;
12: uniform mat4 projectionMatrix;
13: uniform mat4 viewMatrix;
14: uniform mat3 normalMatrix;
15: uniform vec3 cameraPosition;
16: attribute vec3 position;
17: attribute vec3 normal;
18: attribute vec2 uv;
19: #ifdef USE_COLOR
20:     attribute vec3 color;
21: #endif
22: #ifdef USE_MORPHTARGETS
23:     attribute vec3 morphTarget0;
24:     attribute vec3 morphTarget1;
25:     attribute vec3 morphTarget2;
26:     attribute vec3 morphTarget3;
27:     #ifdef USE_MORPHNORMALS
28:         attribute vec3 morphNormal0;
29:         attribute vec3 morphNormal1;
30:         attribute vec3 morphNormal2;
31:         attribute vec3 morphNormal3;
32:     #else
33:         attribute vec3 morphTarget4;
34:         attribute vec3 morphTarget5;
35:         attribute vec3 morphTarget6;
36:         attribute vec3 morphTarget7;
37:     #endif
38: #endif
39: #ifdef USE_SKINNING
40:     attribute vec4 skinIndex;
41:     attribute vec4 skinWeight;
42: #endif
43: 
44: #define PHONG
45: varying vec3 vViewPosition;
46: #ifndef FLAT_SHADED
47:     varying vec3 vNormal;
48: #endif
49: #define PI 3.14159265359
50: #define PI2 6.28318530718
51: #define PI_HALF 1.5707963267949
52: #define RECIPROCAL_PI 0.31830988618
53: #define RECIPROCAL_PI2 0.15915494
54: #define LOG2 1.442695
55: #define EPSILON 1e-6
56: #define saturate(a) clamp( a, 0.0, 1.0 )
57: #define whiteCompliment(a) ( 1.0 - saturate( a ) )
58: float pow2( const in float x ) { return x*x; }
59: float pow3( const in float x ) { return x*x*x; }
60: float pow4( const in float x ) { float x2 = x*x; return x2*x2; }
61: float average( const in vec3 color ) { return dot( color, vec3( 0.3333 ) ); }
62: highp float rand( const in vec2 uv ) {
63:     const highp float a = 12.9898, b = 78.233, c = 43758.5453;
64:     highp float dt = dot( uv.xy, vec2( a,b ) ), sn = mod( dt, PI );
65:     return fract(sin(sn) * c);
66: }
67: struct IncidentLight {
68:     vec3 color;
69:     vec3 direction;
70:     bool visible;
71: };
72: struct ReflectedLight {
73:     vec3 directDiffuse;
74:     vec3 directSpecular;
75:     vec3 indirectDiffuse;
76:     vec3 indirectSpecular;
77: };
78: struct GeometricContext {
79:     vec3 position;
80:     vec3 normal;
81:     vec3 viewDir;
82: };
83: vec3 transformDirection( in vec3 dir, in mat4 matrix ) {
84:     return normalize( ( matrix * vec4( dir, 0.0 ) ).xyz );
85: }
86: vec3 inverseTransformDirection( in vec3 dir, in mat4 matrix ) {
87:     return normalize( ( vec4( dir, 0.0 ) * matrix ).xyz );
88: }
89: vec3 projectOnPlane(in vec3 point, in vec3 pointOnPlane, in vec3 planeNormal ) {
90:     float distance = dot( planeNormal, point - pointOnPlane );
91:     return - distance * planeNormal + point;
92: }
93: float sideOfPlane( in vec3 point, in vec3 pointOnPlane, in vec3 planeNormal ) {
94:     return sign( dot( point - pointOnPlane, planeNormal ) );
95: }
96: vec3 linePlaneIntersect( in vec3 pointOnLine, in vec3 lineDirection, in vec3 pointOnPlane, in vec3 planeNormal ) {
97:     return lineDirection * ( dot( planeNormal, pointOnPlane - pointOnLine ) / dot( planeNormal, lineDirection ) ) + pointOnLine;
98: }
99: mat3 transposeMat3( const in mat3 m ) {
100:    mat3 tmp;
101:    tmp[ 0 ] = vec3( m[ 0 ].x, m[ 1 ].x, m[ 2 ].x );
102:    tmp[ 1 ] = vec3( m[ 0 ].y, m[ 1 ].y, m[ 2 ].y );
103:    tmp[ 2 ] = vec3( m[ 0 ].z, m[ 1 ].z, m[ 2 ].z );
104:    return tmp;
105: }
106: float linearToRelativeLuminance( const in vec3 color ) {
107:    vec3 weights = vec3( 0.2126, 0.7152, 0.0722 );
108:    return dot( weights, color.rgb );
109: }
110: 
111: #if defined( USE_MAP ) || defined( USE_BUMPMAP ) || defined( USE_NORMALMAP ) || defined( USE_SPECULARMAP ) || defined( USE_ALPHAMAP ) || defined( USE_EMISSIVEMAP ) || defined( USE_ROUGHNESSMAP ) || defined( USE_METALNESSMAP )
112:    varying vec2 vUv;
113:    uniform mat3 uvTransform;
114: #endif
115: 
116: #if defined( USE_LIGHTMAP ) || defined( USE_AOMAP )
117:    attribute vec2 uv2;
118:    varying vec2 vUv2;
119: #endif
120: #ifdef USE_DISPLACEMENTMAP
121:    uniform sampler2D displacementMap;
122:    uniform float displacementScale;
123:    uniform float displacementBias;
124: #endif
125: 
126: #ifdef USE_ENVMAP
127:    #if defined( USE_BUMPMAP ) || defined( USE_NORMALMAP ) || defined( PHONG )
128:        varying vec3 vWorldPosition;
129:    #else
130:        varying vec3 vReflect;
131:        uniform float refractionRatio;
132:    #endif
133: #endif
134: 
135: #ifdef USE_COLOR
136:    varying vec3 vColor;
137: #endif
138: #ifdef USE_FOG
139:   varying float fogDepth;
140: #endif
141: 
142: #ifdef USE_MORPHTARGETS
143:    #ifndef USE_MORPHNORMALS
144:    uniform float morphTargetInfluences[ 8 ];
145:    #else
146:    uniform float morphTargetInfluences[ 4 ];
147:    #endif
148: #endif
149: #ifdef USE_SKINNING
150:    uniform mat4 bindMatrix;
151:    uniform mat4 bindMatrixInverse;
152:    #ifdef BONE_TEXTURE
153:        uniform sampler2D boneTexture;
154:        uniform int boneTextureSize;
155:        mat4 getBoneMatrix( const in float i ) {
156:            float j = i * 4.0;
157:            float x = mod( j, float( boneTextureSize ) );
158:            float y = floor( j / float( boneTextureSize ) );
159:            float dx = 1.0 / float( boneTextureSize );
160:            float dy = 1.0 / float( boneTextureSize );
161:            y = dy * ( y + 0.5 );
162:            vec4 v1 = texture2D( boneTexture, vec2( dx * ( x + 0.5 ), y ) );
163:            vec4 v2 = texture2D( boneTexture, vec2( dx * ( x + 1.5 ), y ) );
164:            vec4 v3 = texture2D( boneTexture, vec2( dx * ( x + 2.5 ), y ) );
165:            vec4 v4 = texture2D( boneTexture, vec2( dx * ( x + 3.5 ), y ) );
166:            mat4 bone = mat4( v1, v2, v3, v4 );
167:            return bone;
168:        }
169:    #else
170:        uniform mat4 boneMatrices[ MAX_BONES ];
171:        mat4 getBoneMatrix( const in float i ) {
172:            mat4 bone = boneMatrices[ int(i) ];
173:            return bone;
174:        }
175:    #endif
176: #endif
177: 
178: #ifdef USE_SHADOWMAP
179:    #if 1 > 0
180:        uniform mat4 directionalShadowMatrix[ 1 ];
181:        varying vec4 vDirectionalShadowCoord[ 1 ];
182:    #endif
183:    #if 0 > 0
184:        uniform mat4 spotShadowMatrix[ 0 ];
185:        varying vec4 vSpotShadowCoord[ 0 ];
186:    #endif
187:    #if 4 > 0
188:        uniform mat4 pointShadowMatrix[ 4 ];
189:        varying vec4 vPointShadowCoord[ 4 ];
190:    #endif
191: #endif
192: 
193: #ifdef USE_LOGDEPTHBUF
194:    #ifdef USE_LOGDEPTHBUF_EXT
195:        varying float vFragDepth;
196:    #endif
197:    uniform float logDepthBufFC;
198: #endif
199: #if 0 > 0 && ! defined( PHYSICAL ) && ! defined( PHONG )
200:    varying vec3 vViewPosition;
201: #endif
202: 
203: #ifdef USE_FOG
204:   varying float fogDepth;
205: #endif
206: 
207: uniform float outlineThickness;
208: vec4 calculateOutline( vec4 pos, vec3 objectNormal, vec4 skinned ) {
209:    float thickness = outlineThickness;
210:    const float ratio = 1.0;
211:    vec4 pos2 = projectionMatrix * modelViewMatrix * vec4( skinned.xyz + objectNormal, 1.0 );
212:    vec4 norm = normalize( pos - pos2 );
213:    return pos + norm * thickness * pos.w * ratio;
214: }
215: void main() {
216: #if defined( USE_MAP ) || defined( USE_BUMPMAP ) || defined( USE_NORMALMAP ) || defined( USE_SPECULARMAP ) || defined( USE_ALPHAMAP ) || defined( USE_EMISSIVEMAP ) || defined( USE_ROUGHNESSMAP ) || defined( USE_METALNESSMAP )
217:    vUv = ( uvTransform * vec3( uv, 1 ) ).xy;
218: #endif
219: #if defined( USE_LIGHTMAP ) || defined( USE_AOMAP )
220:    vUv2 = uv2;
221: #endif
222: #ifdef USE_COLOR
223:    vColor.xyz = color.xyz;
224: #endif
225: 
226: vec3 objectNormal = vec3( normal );
227: 
228: #ifdef USE_MORPHNORMALS
229:    objectNormal += ( morphNormal0 - normal ) * morphTargetInfluences[ 0 ];
230:    objectNormal += ( morphNormal1 - normal ) * morphTargetInfluences[ 1 ];
231:    objectNormal += ( morphNormal2 - normal ) * morphTargetInfluences[ 2 ];
232:    objectNormal += ( morphNormal3 - normal ) * morphTargetInfluences[ 3 ];
233: #endif
234: 
235: #ifdef USE_SKINNING
236:    mat4 boneMatX = getBoneMatrix( skinIndex.x );
237:    mat4 boneMatY = getBoneMatrix( skinIndex.y );
238:    mat4 boneMatZ = getBoneMatrix( skinIndex.z );
239:    mat4 boneMatW = getBoneMatrix( skinIndex.w );
240: #endif
241: #ifdef USE_SKINNING
242:    mat4 skinMatrix = mat4( 0.0 );
243:    skinMatrix += skinWeight.x * boneMatX;
244:    skinMatrix += skinWeight.y * boneMatY;
245:    skinMatrix += skinWeight.z * boneMatZ;
246:    skinMatrix += skinWeight.w * boneMatW;
247:    skinMatrix  = bindMatrixInverse * skinMatrix * bindMatrix;
248:    objectNormal = vec4( skinMatrix * vec4( objectNormal, 0.0 ) ).xyz;
249: #endif
250: 
251: vec3 transformedNormal = normalMatrix * objectNormal;
252: #ifdef FLIP_SIDED
253:    transformedNormal = - transformedNormal;
254: #endif
255: 
256: #ifndef FLAT_SHADED
257:    vNormal = normalize( transformedNormal );
258: #endif
259: 
260: vec3 transformed = vec3( position );
261: 
262: #ifdef USE_MORPHTARGETS
263:    transformed += ( morphTarget0 - position ) * morphTargetInfluences[ 0 ];
264:    transformed += ( morphTarget1 - position ) * morphTargetInfluences[ 1 ];
265:    transformed += ( morphTarget2 - position ) * morphTargetInfluences[ 2 ];
266:    transformed += ( morphTarget3 - position ) * morphTargetInfluences[ 3 ];
267:    #ifndef USE_MORPHNORMALS
268:    transformed += ( morphTarget4 - position ) * morphTargetInfluences[ 4 ];
269:    transformed += ( morphTarget5 - position ) * morphTargetInfluences[ 5 ];
270:    transformed += ( morphTarget6 - position ) * morphTargetInfluences[ 6 ];
271:    transformed += ( morphTarget7 - position ) * morphTargetInfluences[ 7 ];
272:    #endif
273: #endif
274: 
275: #ifdef USE_SKINNING
276:    vec4 skinVertex = bindMatrix * vec4( transformed, 1.0 );
277:    vec4 skinned = vec4( 0.0 );
278:    skinned += boneMatX * skinVertex * skinWeight.x;
279:    skinned += boneMatY * skinVertex * skinWeight.y;
280:    skinned += boneMatZ * skinVertex * skinWeight.z;
281:    skinned += boneMatW * skinVertex * skinWeight.w;
282:    transformed = ( bindMatrixInverse * skinned ).xyz;
283: #endif
284: 
285: #ifdef USE_DISPLACEMENTMAP
286:    transformed += normalize( objectNormal ) * ( texture2D( displacementMap, uv ).x * displacementScale + displacementBias );
287: #endif
288: 
289: vec4 mvPosition = modelViewMatrix * vec4( transformed, 1.0 );
290: gl_Position = projectionMatrix * mvPosition;
291: 
292: #ifdef USE_LOGDEPTHBUF
293:    #ifdef USE_LOGDEPTHBUF_EXT
294:        vFragDepth = 1.0 + gl_Position.w;
295:    #else
296:        gl_Position.z = log2( max( EPSILON, gl_Position.w + 1.0 ) ) * logDepthBufFC - 1.0;
297:        gl_Position.z *= gl_Position.w;
298:    #endif
299: #endif
300: 
301: #if 0 > 0 && ! defined( PHYSICAL ) && ! defined( PHONG )
302:    vViewPosition = - mvPosition.xyz;
303: #endif
304: 
305:    vViewPosition = - mvPosition.xyz;
306: #if defined( USE_ENVMAP ) || defined( DISTANCE ) || defined ( USE_SHADOWMAP )
307:    vec4 worldPosition = modelMatrix * vec4( transformed, 1.0 );
308: #endif
309: 
310: #ifdef USE_ENVMAP
311:    #if defined( USE_BUMPMAP ) || defined( USE_NORMALMAP ) || defined( PHONG )
312:        vWorldPosition = worldPosition.xyz;
313:    #else
314:        vec3 cameraToVertex = normalize( worldPosition.xyz - cameraPosition );
315:        vec3 worldNormal = inverseTransformDirection( transformedNormal, viewMatrix );
316:        #ifdef ENVMAP_MODE_REFLECTION
317:            vReflect = reflect( cameraToVertex, worldNormal );
318:        #else
319:            vReflect = refract( cameraToVertex, worldNormal, refractionRatio );
320:        #endif
321:    #endif
322: #endif
323: 
324: #ifdef USE_SHADOWMAP
325:    #if 1 > 0
326:    
327:        vDirectionalShadowCoord[ 0 ] = directionalShadowMatrix[ 0 ] * worldPosition;
328:    
329:    #endif
330:    #if 0 > 0
331:    
332:    #endif
333:    #if 4 > 0
334:    
335:        vPointShadowCoord[ 0 ] = pointShadowMatrix[ 0 ] * worldPosition;
336:    
337:        vPointShadowCoord[ 1 ] = pointShadowMatrix[ 1 ] * worldPosition;
338:    
339:        vPointShadowCoord[ 2 ] = pointShadowMatrix[ 2 ] * worldPosition;
340:    
341:        vPointShadowCoord[ 3 ] = pointShadowMatrix[ 3 ] * worldPosition;
342:    
343:    #endif
344: #endif
345: 
346: 
347: #ifdef USE_FOG
348: fogDepth = -mvPosition.z;
349: #endif
350: #if ! defined( LAMBERT ) && ! defined( PHONG ) && ! defined( TOON ) && ! defined( PHYSICAL )
351:    #ifndef USE_ENVMAP
352:        vec3 objectNormal = normalize( normal );
353:    #endif
354: #endif
355: #ifdef FLIP_SIDED
356:    objectNormal = -objectNormal;
357: #endif
358: #ifdef DECLARE_TRANSFORMED
359:    vec3 transformed = vec3( position );
360: #endif
361: gl_Position = calculateOutline( gl_Position, objectNormal, vec4( transformed, 1.0 ) );
362: 
363: #ifdef USE_FOG
364: fogDepth = -mvPosition.z;
365: #endif
366: }
```

Comment: Sounds like it could be a bug in the library. Are you running the latest THREE.js? Can you post a running example to look at?

Comment: Might be a bug in the **example** :D

Comment: This is probably a bug with the outline example, as @manthrax has pointed out. The outline thing is extending shaders (and using a lot of regex at that) so it probably didn't account for this right.

Comment: It would be really, really hard to post a running example.  The only thing I have to work from is our internal prototype, which is confidential, and I just don't have the js/threejs experience to build a minimally reproducible example.  I'm pretty limited to tinkering with the code I have and trying to apply code I see in examples.  I do see in the OutlineEffect code, I don't see any reference to `fogDepth`, but its importing a lot of fog-related headers.  I'm hoping the author of the example will see this question...

Comment: Well, anything can be in your `THREE.Scene` and this is a pretty complex example. It creates a specific shader out of each material. There's only one chunk i see that would ever mention this but i don't see a way you could possibly have it conflicting with something else. What kind of materials do you have in your scene? https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/7cd6612650301fdd0bcb60683de2b9bae4707321/examples/js/effects/OutlineEffect.js#L199

Comment: My guess is that this has absolutely nothing to do with `OutlineEffect`. Try commenting it out and see if the error is still there. This is extra confusing because the effect should override your composer.

Comment: Well yes it works without OutlineEffect -- the issue I'm seeking help on is getting the OutlineEffect and fog to work together.

Comment: literally no matter what you do, the outline effect pass itself should either not even compile that variable, or at least properly define it only once. This is really weird :( **The whole dump of the error would help, to see what kind of shader you even ended up with.**

Comment: Please add entire log from the error (you should see line 204) there

Comment: You're right - I realize now there's more to the error log than I thought.  I'll edit the question, thanks.

Comment: I dont understand how you end up with that GLSL at all. The only mention of `fogDepth` in the entire library is not a varying but a temporary variable in the fragment shader. Impossible to tell what's going on without seeing the entire shader and possibly knowing more about your scene.

Comment: Why is it on line 204 in your title and now on 178, what did you change?

Comment: I had realized you were right and there was more error logging. The line 178 one is the first reported error.  I've now added the source dump from the error that refers to line 204.

Comment: you cut it after the line which again didn't help, no way of telling where you got that shader from. It's a lot of code, but its needed.

Comment: Ok I've added it.

Comment: @pailhead, since you made me go through the code, I was able to fix it, it required commenting out this line:   `"#include <fog_pars_vertex>"`. I'm still seeing warnings, so a better fix is due, but if you want to write it up as an answer, I'll accept it so you get the points.  Thanks!